# How do get int value from Choicebox

Tags: java, user-interface, button, javafx

i need help with my choiceBox  to connect it with a button to verify the choice  i made. the task i currently working on is a Ferry Simulator so for example i want to embark a car with passengers, the amount of passengers should be selected from the choicebox and the embark the car with a button. To Embark the vehicle you must have  int value in to the car object, my Question is how can i  get int from choicebox and how can i connect it to the Button. Thanks

```
    ChoiceBox cbCar = new ChoiceBox();
    cbCar.getItems().addAll("0 Passengers",1,2,3,4);
    cbCar.getSelectionModel();
    cbCar.setLayoutX(100);
    cbCar.setLayoutY(65); 

    // Button for car 
    Button bCar = new Button("Embark");
    bCar.setLayoutX(220);
    bCar.setLayoutY(65);
    bCar.setOnAction(event -> {     
       Car ca = new Car(int passengers );   // from the choicebox   
        ferry.embark(ca)    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
choiceBox.getValue().toString();
```

This can be used to display the selected value.